# Using inheritance and dialog box in java

Tags: java, inheritance, netbeans, joptionpane

I have three classes in java that i created:

CollegeCourse

```
package CollegeCourse;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CollegeCourse {

protected String Dept;
protected int CourseNum;
protected int Cred;
protected int fee;
protected int Charge = 120;
protected int labfee;

public void inputDepartment(){
    Dept = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Department");
}

public void inputCourseNumber(){
    String CourseNumString = new String(" ");
    CourseNumString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Course Number");
    CourseNum = Integer.parseInt(CourseNumString);
}

public void inputCredits(){
    String CredString = new String(" ");
    CredString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Credits");
    Cred = Integer.parseInt(CredString);
}

 public void displayNonLabCourse(){
    fee = Cred * Charge;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Dept + CourseNum + 
            "\nNon-lab Course" + "\n" + Cred +" Credits" + "\nTotal fee is $" + fee);
 }
```

}

LabCourse

```
package CollegeCourse;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class LabCourse extends CollegeCourse {

 public void displayLabCourse(){
    labfee = fee + 50;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Dept + CourseNum + 
            "\nLab Course" + "\n" + Cred +" Credits" + "\nTotal fee is $" + fee);
 }
 }
```

UseCourse

```
package CollegeCourse;
public class UseCourse{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CollegeCourse college = new CollegeCourse();
    college.inputDepartment();
    college.inputCourseNumber();
    college.inputCredits();
    college.displayNonLabCourse();
    }
}
```

How can i make the UseCourse class display the LabCourse display method when the user enters a certain department like "BIO"???

Create a class named CollegeCourse that includes data fields that hold the department
(for example, ENG), the course number (for example, 101), the credits (for example 3),
and fee for the course (for example, $360). All of the fields are required as arguments
to the constructor, except for the fee, which is calculated at $120 per credit hour.
Include a display() method that displays course data. Create a subclass named LabCourse that
adds $50 to the course fee. Override the parent class display() method to indicate that the
course is a lab course to display all the data. Write an application named UseCourse that
prompts the user for information. If the user enters a class in any of the following departments,
create a LabCourse: BIO, CHM, CIS, or PHY. If the user enters any other departments, create
a CollegeCourse that does not include the lab fee. Then display the course data. Save the files
as CollegeCourse.java, LabCourse.java, and UseCourse.java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite different to your original implementation. But I believe it does what you want it to. There's probably a better way of implementing it, but I'm only implementing based on the information you've given me. Hope you understand it all...

UseCourse:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class UseCourse
{   
    public UseCourse()
    {
        CollegeCourse college;
        // Collect all the necessary data first to determine whether it is a lab course or not.
        String dept = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Department");

        String courseNumString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Course Number");
        int courseNum = Integer.parseInt(courseNumString);

        String credString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Credits");
        int cred = Integer.parseInt(credString);

        // Now that we have the info we can ask the question.
        if (dept.equals("BIO") | dept.equals("CHM") | dept.equals("CIS") | dept.equals("PHY"))
        {college = new LabCourse(dept, courseNum, cred);}

        else {college = new LabCourse(dept, courseNum, cred);}
        college.display();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {new UseCourse();}
}
```

CollegeCourse:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CollegeCourse {

protected String dept;
protected int courseNum;
protected int cred;
protected int fee;
protected int Charge = 120;
protected int labfee;

public CollegeCourse(String dept, int courseNum, int cred)
{
    this.dept = dept;
    this.courseNum = courseNum;
    this.cred = cred;
    fee = cred * Charge;
}

public void display(){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dept + courseNum + 
            "\nNon-lab Course" + "\n" + cred +" Credits" + "\nTotal fee is $" + fee);
 }
}
```

LabCourse:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class LabCourse extends CollegeCourse 
{
    public LabCourse(String dept, int courseNum, int cred)
    {super(dept, courseNum, cred);}

    public void display()
    {
        fee += 50;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dept + courseNum + 
                "\nLab Course" + "\n" + cred +" Credits" + "\nTotal fee is $" + fee);
    }  
}
```

Comment: i want to use an if-else method so i could filter the input in the inputdepartment and prompt the displayLabCourse if the user inputs a certain department. how can i do that?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming not every CollegeCourse has a LabCourse? In which case how do you differentiate all the courses into the two sets of LabCourse and No LabCourse?

Comment: it will be differentiated base on the user's input in the department. The LabCourse will only be used if the user inputs: BIO, CHM, CIS, or PHY in the department field

Comment: Okay, I don't think putting the JOptionPane: Dept = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Department"); should be within the CollegeCourse class. Personally I would put it in the main Method. That way you could either create a new CollegeCourse OR a new LabCourse. I'll try and rewrite my answer to suit.

Comment: if i put the input fields in the main class it has an error that it should not be static

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it without checking. One moment while I clear the errors

Comment: Try that, any questions/ problems. Let me know.

Comment: Strange. I have tested the code and I had 3 dialog boxes appear one after the other. I don't know whether it will make any difference. But for speed I didn't implement the package details at the top because I was working in netbeans.

Comment: Well I've only copied your original logic when I implemented. Explain to me the difference between LabCourses and non LabCourses in regards to their cost?

Comment: Here is a part of the question given to us that explains the fee:
the fee, which is calculated at $120 per credit hour.
Include a display() method that displays course data. Create a subclass named LabCourse that
adds $50 to the course fee. Override the parent class display() method to indicate that the
course is a lab course to display all the data.

Comment: Okay, in class "CollegeCourse:" in method: "public void displayNonLabCourse" you want to move the line: "fee = cred * Charge;" into the method: "public CollegeCourse(String dept, int courseNum, int cred)". Put it at the bottom of the method - AFTER "this.cred = cred"

Comment: THEN... in class "LabCourse:" you want to change the variable "labfee" to "fee". I think this is a typo from your behalf.

Comment: Just going over your quote: "Override the parent class display()". This program doesn't do this exactly, would you like me to rewrite the code so that it meets this specification?

Comment: can i post the full question? so you can see what the program is all about?

Comment: Class: UseCourse() at line: "else {college = new LabCourse(dept, courseNum, cred);}" replace the work "LabCourse" with "CollegeCourse".

Comment: Yeah, my fault. Rushing too much.

Comment: How can i implement the toUpperCase line within this code? i want the entered department to be display in all caps so if the user for example enters bio instead of BIO it will still display that it is a lab course.

Comment: After "dept = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Department");" Put: "dept = dept.toUpperCase();" - I've not tested this. But should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using inheritance then you should have same method name something like "displayCourse" in both CollegeCourse and LabCourse classes. Then based on the inputs by the user:

```
CollegeCourse c = null;
if (userSelectedCollegeCourse) {
c = new CollegeCourse(param1, ...);
}else{
c = new LabCourse(param1, ...);
}

c.displayCourse();
```

Comment: can you explain this code? im new and i don't understand the syntax

Comment: When you have same method i.e displayCourse in super class CollegeCourse and LabCourse then calling c.displayCourse with use CollegeCourse or LabCourse's method depending on what you put in c. What I am suggesting is initializing c with either CollegeCourse or LabCourse based on inputs by user.

Comment: can you show a full example with my code? i can't quite understand your explanation. sorry